# How to model a dumpster wheel?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I have been trying to model a dumpster wheel in Blender, but it turned out to be trickier than I thought. In particular, I just can't figure out how to do the central part (with the holes). I have tried this a couple of times, but ended up with nothing but a mess. Could you show me the correct way to do this? I'm not completely new to Blender, so there's no need to be too specific.

Here's the reference picture:

[image: reference picture]

http://www.jtmetal.com/steelcaster2.jpg

[And just when I thought I was already past the “beginner stage" in Blender before this. Meaby I should quit Blender and throw my computer out of the window.]

Comment: You will always manage to throw computer out of the window because of this problem but I think it will provide you only new problems. You might want to show screenshots of the "mess" you've got when faced problems, although this shape is modeled from hollow cylinder with 2 loopcuts in the middle to extrude inwards the rest shape

Comment: please use the edit link at the bottom of your question and add more information detailing what you have done so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I’m sure there are many ways to accomplish this. Here’s one possibility.

SHIFT + “A” Add Mesh > Circle with 64 vertices (Top View “7”).

[image]

TAB into Edit Mode press “E” and “S” Extrude Scale three times.

[image]

Select this vertex and press SHIFT + V and slide it until the corresponding edge is parallel to the X Axis.

[image]

Repeat for this vertex until the corresponding edge is parallel to the Y Axis.

[image]

Select 3/4 of the vertices and press “X” choose Vertices from the drop down menu to delete them.

[image]

Add a Mirror Modifier check off “Y” “Z” (“X” is checked by default). Also add a Subdivision Surface Modifier (Change the View to 2). Tab into Object Mode and select Smooth Shading then Tab back into Edit Mode.

[image]

Add two Loop Cuts (CTRL + “R”).

[image]

Select the following ten interior faces and press “X” and select Faces from the drop down menu to delete them.

[image]

Press “A” to select all and press “E” to extrude them up.

[image]

Select the following interior faces and press “X” to delete them.

[image]

Check off Clipping in the Mirror Modifier.
Select these faces and press “E” to Extrude them up.

[image]
[image]

DE-Select these six faces then press “E” to extrude the remaining faces up again.

[image]
[image]

Tighten up some of the edges with Loop Cuts.

[image]

Comment: This was really helpful and easy to follow solution. I also learned  a few new things about the Mirror Modifier (like how to remove those ugly seams you get after applying it by removing the interior faces.)